# create_task that calls ref class sealed constructor gives 'create_task': no matching overloaded function found

Tags: asynchronous, uwp, task, c++-cx

I have created to call the constructor of MyClass, My class is defined as ref class Myclass sealed and this function is defined as static under public

```
IAsyncOperation<MyClass^>^ MyNameSpace::MyClass::CreateAsync()
{
    return create_task(MyClass()).then([](MyClass^ objectx)
    {
        return ref new MyClass();
        //return std::make_shared<MyClass>();
    });
}
```

this is giving me bunch of errors like:

```
Error   C2672   'Concurrency::details::declval': no matching overloaded function found

Error   C2770   invalid explicit template argument(s) for '_Ty &&Concurrency::details::declval(void)'

Error   C2672   'Concurrency::details::_FilterValidTaskType': no matching overloaded function found

Error   C2672   'create_task': no matching overloaded function found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constructor is not an asynchronous operation so can't be used as a parameter to `create_task`. If it takes a long time and you want to run the constructor as a task, use `create_async` instead.

[`create_async` takes a function-like object (eg a lambda) and runs it as a task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/520a6dff-9324-4df2-990d-302e3050af6a.aspx#create_async_function).

From your example above:

```
IAsyncOperation<MyClass^>^ MyNameSpace::MyClass::CreateAsync()
{
    return concurrency::create_async([]
    {
        return ref new MyClass();
    });
}
```

This will spin up a task to run the lambda (which constructs your class) and then wraps it in a WinRT `IAsyncOperation<>` that you can use. Since your constructor doesn't do anything, I'm not sure why you want it to be asynchronous though (unless you omitted a bunch of expensive calls).

Comment: could you please elaborate ? 

my constructor is:
`MyNameSpace::MyClass::MyClass()
 :Param1(Windows::Graphics::Imaging::BitmapSize{ 0u, 0u }),
 Param2(Windows::Graphics::Imaging::BitmapSize{ 0u, 0u })
{

}`
how should i proceed with this type of const? 
-thanks